# Application Token is Different

Tags: facebook-graph-api

On this page:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-app-tokens/

It describes how to get the app access token, yet the token it returns is different than the one in the open Graph "Get Code" example.  The latter is the only one that works.  How can I get the second access token using the API?  When I try to use the first example, I basically get something back that looks like "application ID|secret key" which is different than the real access token.

Comment: What's your problem? that the app access token you receive from the access_token endpoint doesn't work?

Comment: No it doesn't work.  The one from the "get code" section works, but it changes over time.

Comment: There should be no expiry on an app access token retrieved using the instructions on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as documentation states, you will get

```
access_token=YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

string back from the API call. Even though it LOOKS like "application ID|secret key HASH" - it is a valid access token you can use to publish to user's wall. You can verify it's a proper access token using Debug toll from FB: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug - just paste the token there.

The reason it might not work for you is because you are trying to publish something to the user's wall who did not authorize your app. Look here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ - for example of how to use your app ID to make user authorize the app. You need to request **publish_stream** permission for your app from user in order to be able to publish as the app to the user's wall.

And going back to the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-app-tokens/):

> Note that the app access token is for publishing purposes permitted by
>   the publish_actions and publish_stream permissions. You will be unable
>   to retrieve information about the status update post with the given ID
>   using the app access token. Instead, you should use a user access
>   token for such purposes.

hope that helps.

Comment: I have set it up for publish_stream and here is the error I get:

"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

Here is the code:

`
$data['access_token'] = '[MY APP KEY IS HERE]';
  
return $this->post_data_to('https://graph.facebook.com/me/' . $namespace . ':' . $action, $data, true);

`

Comment: please read your link - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-app-tokens/ -  more careful. It says there: You should be able to use an app access token to make API calls, in the form of POST requests, to publish information on behalf of the user, just as you would with a user access token.

Note that because you are not using a user access token, all calls to publish information on behalf of the user should reference /[USER FB ID] instead of /me.

Comment: that means: 1. You cannot use app token to get information about the user; 2. You should NOT use "/me/" but need to use "/USER_ID/" instead.

Comment: Gotcha..  Sorry, but there is quite a bit of documentation to go through here and it spans multiple programming languages and various methods.  It is easy to get lost.  I think this resolves the issue though and thanks for your time! :)